# java: If notify() is always called before the lock release, how could a waiting threads acquire this same lock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I think that I already know the answer to that question, however, I would like to read your opinions to make sure that I really understand how java thread's state machine (or diagram) works.

Imagine that Thread A runs the **notify()** just before return a given value:

```
public class baz{

    // Thread B runs this:
    public synchronized void bar(){
       wait();
    } 

    // Thread A runs this:
    public synchronized int foo(){
       notify();
       return 11;
    }
}
```

**notify()** will be called before Thread A releases the lock (that will occurs "after" the **return 11**; statement). 
So, how could a Thread B, that is waiting for this lock (via **wait()** method), acquire the lock that is still held by Thread A? 
Note that, when thread B is notified the lock has not yet been released by Thread A.

So what I think of this situation is the following:

After calling **wait()**, Thread B will change its state from **Running** to **Waiting**.
After receiving the notification (from Thread A **notify()** method), Thread B will return from **wait()**, change its state to **Runnable** and try to acquire the lock. Since the lock is not yet released by Thread A, Thread B will be blocked on the object's monitor and pass its state from **Runnable** to **Blocked**.
Eventually, after Thread A releases the lock, Thread B will acquire the lock and pass its state from **Blocked** to **Running**.

Is this right? What I want to understand with this question is *what happens* to a thread that returns from  a **wait()** which is synchronized by an already acquired lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is correct.

When you call `wait()` on an object, the calling thread will be added to the object's [*wait set*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2). When it is `notify()`ied, it will be removed from that wait set, and perform [a lock action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1) on the object (it's within a `synchronized` block on that object). That lock action will block the current thread until it is complete, ie. locked the object monitor.

This is the exact same behavior that two threads would have when trying to enter a `synchronized` block on the same object. The first thread to reach would lock the object monitor, completing the lock object immediately. The other thread blocks until its lock action is complete, ie. after the first thread unlocks the monitor.

Comment: it's mean return statement could not release the lock? and the question's example could be DeadLock? and we should not use return statement in synchronized method? can you explain please or give me link that could clear my these concepts.

Comment: @UnKnown `return`, in itself, does not release the lock. If the `return` statement appears with a `synchronized` block or method, it's the action caused by the `return`, ie. leaving that block or method, that will release the lock.